# No suitable method found for show(ActionBar,String) method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable

Tags: java, android

Getting

```
Error:(192, 23) error: no suitable method found for show(ActionBar,String)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(actual argument ActionBar cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction by method invocation conversion)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(actual argument ActionBar cannot be converted to FragmentManager by method invocation conversion)
```

when trying to create a custom dialog box, getting error in `dialog.show(getSupportActionBar(), "dialog");` this code.

Here is my brief code:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    Button settBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    settBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();
            dialog.show(getSupportActionBar(), "dialog");

        }
    });
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.Animation_CustomDialog;
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        TextView message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
        message.setText(">>>>>>>");
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.positive_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this.Thanks in advance.....

Comment: dialog.show() accepts either FragmentTransaction or FragmentManager as the first parameter, why are passing an ActionBar?

Comment: Actually its a  extend class of  ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using  `FragmentManager`

```
FragmentManager fm;
fm= getFragmentManager();
CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();
dialog.show(fm , "dialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment();
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit? You might want to read [How Do I Write A Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).